# xcode 5, and 4.6.3 Can't load a rtfd.zip file into UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Prior to upgrading to xcode 4.6.3 the following code worked perfectly. Now it does NOT. I get a blank white page. This code is placed after super viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"info.rtfd" ofType:@"zip"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Comment: We'll need more information. What's your window supposed to look like? Is your web view created in code or from IB?

Comment: Is the file in your bundle really named `info.rtfd.zip`?

Comment: The web view is created in IB. The window contains some formatted text, a couple of links, and a small .png file. As I said, it worked perfectly before the upgrade. Now, no go. The file name is referenced correctly. (As I said, it worked previous to the upgrade to 4.6.3. Doesn't work in 5 either.

Comment: Anyone have a clue what the problem is?

Comment: appears this is an ios7 bug. Filed a bug report. Hopefully will be fixed in next seed.